# Objective-C block callbacks, weak references and disposed objects

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, objective-c-blocks, weak-references

I am attempting to implement a more or less straightforward callback mechanism using blocks in Objective-C. My concern, however, is how this will work with ARC and memory management.

Consider the scenario where I have a view controller that is displaying some relevant information from a model object that supports my block callback mechanism that is fired whenever a field on that object changes (assume I don't want to use KVO for this). The view controller registers a block that references `self` and updates various aspects of the UI inside this block.

Now suppose the view disappears, but the model still exists in memory as it may be referenced elsewhere. What happens now when the object changes and calls its registered callback blocks? Presumably the blocks themselves will persist, but the moment I try to reference `self` I will get nil. (?)

*What I want to happen is to only actually call the callback block if its "target" (the view controller in this case) is still alive.*

First question is, is there any way for the blocks themselves to be disposed-of automatically when the view controller is disposed? For example what would happen if I kept weak references to the blocks themselves? I'm guessing this wouldn't work because the blocks would disappear immediately with nothing else referencing them.

My second idea was to keep a weak reference to the target alongside the block itself, such that I can check the target reference to see if it is alive or not before calling the block (and if I discover that a target is dead I can simply remove the corresponding block).

My question then is what data structure should I use to store these--perhaps a struct or class that maintains a weak reference to a target and a strong reference to the block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second idea is actually kind of interesting.

```
typedef void (^NotificationHandler)(Foo* bar, What* ever);

@interface NotificationWrapper : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, weak) id canary;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NotificationHandler handler;
@end
```

You can keep these wrapper objects in a simple NSMutableArray, within perhaps a dictionary of notification handlers.  Clients can register and unregister for notifications via, say:

```
- (void)registerForNotification:(NSString*)notificationKey 
                         canary:(id)canary
                        handler:(NotificationHandler)handler;
```

When it's time to fire a notification, check if the canary is alive before calling the handler.  If the canary is dead, remove the wrapper from your notification handler list.

```
for (NotificationWrapper* wrapper in notificationHandlers)
{
    if (wrapper.canary)
    {
         wrapper.handler(foo, bar);
    }
    else
    { 
         [deadHandlers addObject:wrapper];
    }
}

for (id handler in deadHandlers)
{
    [notificationHandlers removeObject:handler];
}
```

So what does this get you in the end?  It saves the client from having to manually unregister its notifications, which is nice and avoids a common problem with KVO and `NSNotificationCenter`.  But it doesn't save the clients from dealing with potential reference cycles in the blocks they provide.

Comment: Love your choice of variable name. ;)

Answer (score 2):

I've been using following code snippet for some time and works perfectly:

```
__weak id this = self;
void (^blockObject)() = ^(){

    __strong typeof(self) strongThis = this; // Or __strong MyClass *strongThis = this;
    [strongThis someMethod];
};
```

If I remember correctly Apple suggested this approach at one of WWDC's. Reason for that is that if you use only **__weak** reference your object may release and your __weak reference will point to some garbage in memory. But when you make **__strong** reference to **__weak**, after your controller releases your **__strong** reference will be **nil**. Just as you want it to be.

Comment: While this is certainly good practice, I'd like to avoid calling the callback *at all* if `self` is disposed, and have the callback mechanism be smart enough to figure this out somehow rather than delegating this responsibility to each and every block.

Comment: I think my idea of passing `self` as a parameter to my callback register method (and storing this in a weak reference) has some promise.

Comment: I agree with you but sometimes your code will be huge mess if you want to release all blocks from your dealloc. Imagine you have controller with web services which, of course, use blocks for delegating response. I.e. if you call 8 web services where each service is some kind of NSOperation, in the end you will have to retain 8 instances. It can be pretty annoying for other programmers too.

Comment: @chaiguy I'm not sure why it's necessary to do that at all. The efficiency gained from not calling the block is negligible, and it makes for some messy code. I would stick with best practices.

Comment: @AnthonyM It's not for efficiency, it's for code safety. If I rely on the implementor of the block verifying that the target is still alive (which granted they should be doing) it introduces the potential for bugs/crashes. If the implementation of the callback system can do this itself, it eliminates or reduces the potential for bad things to happen. Basically I'm taking that check and moving it up the chain a level so that it automatically gets applied to every block guaranteed.

Answer (score 1):

> My second idea was to keep a weak reference to the target alongside the block itself, such that I can check the target reference to see if it is alive or not before calling the block (and if I discover that a target is dead I can simply remove the corresponding block).

This seems like it would work, but I believe recommended best practices are:

```
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
returnType (^myBlock)(parameterTypes) = ^returnType(parameters) {
    __strong typeof(weakSelf) strongSelf = weakSelf;
    if (strongSelf) {
        // your block implementation
    }
};
```

If you really don't want the block to fire at all then you can go ahead and keep a weak reference to the target with the block, but this seems like messy code.

Comment: Problem with this is that if your object gets deallocated, your weakSelf reference will not be nil. It will point to some garbage in memory and IF condition will be true. Knowing this you will probably have some crash in the end.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the reference to strong self. Editing now.

Comment: Weak reference never points to garbage, it will be nil. Go read compiler docs, it's all described clearly.

Comment: You define strong reference inside of block to make sure it doesn't die half way thru, not because you're afraid of zombies.

Answer (score 0):

> Now suppose the view disappears, but the model still exists in memory
>   as it may be referenced elsewhere. What happens now when the object
>   changes and calls its registered callback blocks? Presumably the
>   blocks themselves will persist, but the moment I try to reference self
>   I will get nil. (?)

This doesn't really make sense to me. You said that the view controller registered some callback blocks with reference `self` (the view controller object itself). And you said the blocks themselves persist. Therefore, the view controller will persist, because it is being retained by the block which is alive.

Comment: Is this true? Will a block with closures into a view controller keep that view controller alive indefinitely? That doesn't seem right, or else it would cause all sorts of memory leaks in any code that used blocks would it not? I'm admittedly not 100% on how block closures work with ARC.

Comment: @chaiguy: Yes, this is very fundamental to how blocks work. The block contains a copy of captured variables. The captured variable is a strong reference to the view controller, so the block has a strong reference to the view controller. That doesn't mean the view controller is kept alive indefinitely -- it means the view controller is kept alive as long as the block is alive. You should go back and read more about blocks. The strong references that blocks have are no different from the references that any other object has. It can cause leaks no more and no less than other objects can.

Comment: But if the block only references a `__weak` verison of self (as per the other answers) this should be fine, correct?

Comment: @chaiguy: Yes, if it uses a `__weak` variable that is a copy of `self` (of course it won't be called `self`, it would be called `weakSelf` or something), then it could be `nil` when you use it in the block. But isn't that what you were worried about in the first place in your question? With your existing code (with `self`), you don't have any possibility of `self` being `nil`, which is what I'm pointing out.

Comment: I was more interested in avoiding calling the block if self is nil, however it is good to know that not using a weak reference to self could cause leaks.

Comment: @chaiguy: But it's not true that it will cause leaks. It will only cause leaks if there is a retain cycle. The block has a reference to the view controller. But there is no retain cycle unless the view controller also has a reference (or chain of references) to the block.